# Need WFS-T for field work on GeoServer/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, ubuntu, wfs-t, tomcat

I'm using a Boundless install of OpenGeo Suite on Ubuntu Server 12.04 with Tomcat 7. 
I need to allow remote access to update from the field. I can edit features fine on network, but not remotely.

*Originally added:
"I found this tutorial http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html on the topic, but couldn't find the httpd.conf file anywhere."

This info proved irrelevant to the problem*

Comment: Do you have Apache2 installed?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe this is my problem. I assumed Tomcat and Apache was synonymous since Tomcat is by Apache. Could you explain the role Apache and Tomcat each play then?

Comment: Okay, a quick look and it seems Apache just serves static web pages, tomcat serves applications, so I think that Apache isn't going to get me what I ultimately need: WFS-T capability remotely. So the httpd file is a red herring.

Comment: In that recipe the role of Apache is to proxy the requests which are coming to the default port 80 to the port where GeoServer is running. Nothing to do with GIS really. Instead of using Apache as a proxy you can configure Tomcat to run in some other port or configure the firewall to allow direct access to the port where GeoServer is found by default.

Comment: I've got my router port forwarding to the GeoServer. I can go to GeoServer, see the map, and bring in layers to QGIS and Arbiter from online, but can't push edits through unless I'm on network.

Comment: Even with port forwarding enabled, I'm wondering if the firewall is only allowing data out, not in. Does that sound likely? Or maybe it's a setting on Ubuntu?

Comment: if you turn up logging there may be something in the log file

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it wasn't a GeoServer or network/firewall setting, but that the source data was not in an agreeable projection though I had set GS to reproject to 3857.

I had been trying to edit a multipolygon layer, and even though I was drawing inside the bounding box, the reprojection was moving it someplace else well outside the bbox and I can only assume this was causing the rejection. I discovered this when I tried editing a point layer in the same projection, but apparently it isn't as picky about the bbox as it was accepting it, but well outside the bbox. I only discovered this when as  [iant](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/79/iant) suggested looking at the log file that I saw the attributes that I had assigned to a point showing up and used QGIS to confirm that the point had in fact came through, just nowhere near where I had placed it. Once I transformed the projections of the PostGIS tables to 3857 and removed and brought them back into GS, both were editing as expected.

But it is interesting that on network wasn't affected by the projection difference, but outside the network it was (I don't know if this would be considered a bug).

Thank you everyone for your help.